# Lagrange polynomials sum to one

Tags: summation, products

I've been stuck on this problem for a few weeks now. Any help?

Prove: 
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=0,j\neq i}^{n}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}=1$

The sum of lagrange polynomials should be one, otherwise affine combinations of with these make no sense.

EDIT:
Can anybody prove this by actually working out the sum and product? The other proofs make no sense to me. Imagine explaining this to someone who has never heard of lagrange.

Comment: What happens when you use Lagrange interpolation to interpolate $f(x) = 1$? Keep in mind that the interpolation polynomial will be unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $P$ the polynomial with degree $n$ defined by
$$P(x)=\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n}\prod_{j=0,j\neq i}^{n}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}\right)-1$$
then we see easily that
$$P(x_i)=0,\;\quad\forall i=0,\ldots,n$$
so $P$ has $n+1$ distinct roots hence it's the zero polynomial due to the D'Alembert's theorem. Conclude.

Comment: I had to look up lagrange interpolation (I was studying lagrange polynomials independently), but now I get what you're saying. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Throw in the $f(x_i)$ and what happens if they are all 1?